# Java Web-Start Desktop Icon Lauch Error Unable to Load Resources

Tags: java, desktop, shortcut, jnlp, java-web-start

I have created a JavaFx webstart application with ant script and enabled desktop shortcut.
This application signed and given all permissions and hosted in a local server for testing.
when it is launch in the system through web start link the icon got created on the desk top in users machine along with application started.
Now the issue is once the application is closed and next time launched from the desktop shortcut; the applications starts and after a while the desktop icon will be refreshed all it self. Now if i try to lauch the application again from the shortcut it fails with the following error.

> Application Error
>
> Unable to launch the application.

The details [More Information shows]

> Error: unable to load resource:

(and points to the jnlp in the local machine)

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\42\Sample.jnlp
> (The system cannot find the file specified)

Now the problem is even for the first launch the file is not there in the given path but it launched. This issue will be after the icon is refreshed.

Any help/solution greatly appreciated.

---

### Question Updated with Few Results

When tested the JNLP with the  JaNeLA
I got the few errors

The errors show following syntax as unrecognized.

```
<jfx:javafx-runtime>
```

Here is the JNLP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="SAmpleAppp.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>SAmpleAppp</title>
    <vendor>XXX</vendor>
    <description>XXX</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="SAmpleAppp.jar" size="591973" download="eager" />
    <jar href="libs/guava-13.0.1.jar" size="1914716" download="eager" />
    <jar href="libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar" size="490849" download="eager" />
    <jar href="libs/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar" size="234548" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <shortcut><desktop/></shortcut>
  <applet-desc  width="1085" height="750" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="SAmpleAppp" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="1085" height="750" main-class="XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.SAmpleAppp"  name="SAmpleAppp" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Did you see any error???
Thanks.

Comment: Check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  Correct anything identified as an error.

Comment: Hey Andy, Please check the updated q..

Comment: oops.. just made a typo by making your name short.. its Andrew.

Comment: Type @PersonName (or @ followed by 'Pe' & it will pop up).

Answer (score 0):

**This is a bug in Java Web Start. and Ant Tasks**

Refer to the question with more details at JIRA.

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27746